# uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery

I am getting **uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@name='rbRewSelectionGroup']** when I load may page which has this in it at the bottom:

```
<script language="javascript">

    $("input[@name='rbRewSelectionGroup']").click(function()
                                                   {
                                                        $(this).closest("form").submit();
                                                   });
</script>
```

I am not seeing it.  I do not see anything wrong with this code at all.  I do have the jQuery (1.4.2) library loaded with the page.

Answer (score 3):

In current versions of jQuery you no longer need the `@` prefix for attributes ([it was removed in the jQuery 1.3 release](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3#Upgrading)).

Your [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) should look like this:

```
$("input[name='rbRewSelectionGroup']")
```

Comment: so....looks like jQuery 1.4 is not backwards compatible with @?? that seems a bit odd

Comment: great.  Because I just upgraded our code to jQuery 1.4.2 because I wanted to use the latest jQuery library with the new jQuery UI...I hope I did not break anything.  I was told that for most all of the code in 1.3, that it's compatible with 1.4

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Are you *sure* you are going from 1.3 to 1.4? It sounds like you were on 1.2.x previously, you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/eB9TL/ Change the framework on the left and click run, you'll see it errors in 1.3 and 1.4, but works in 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

actually the main reason is refer to bad selector, and the bad selector also refer to bad html attribute or tag name,and in your code:

```
$("input[@name='rbRewSelectionGroup']")
```

the new jquery will search for the element

```
<input @name="rbRewSelectionGroup" />
```

witch will have a bad attribute name ;)